# How do I get edges on a matlab surf plot in only the y direction?

Tags: matlab

Trying to get a surf plot where there would be visible edges but only in the y-direction so that they would be at certain intervals of the x-axis.

Comment: I think what you are asking is the `waterfall` plot, see this help page: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waterfall.html

Comment: @FangQ That's exactly what I needed. Thank you!